# how to add space between navbar-brand and items in wordpress bootstrap navigation?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put my brand on the left hand side, and with a bit of space in between, I would like my navigation links to the right hand side.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY NAVBRAND</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
       <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
        ?>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

Now to do that, I am trying to add this to my css so that there is space between the a tag (with class navbar-brand) and the div(with class collapse).

```
  .navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
   }
```

But it is not working and the label and links are right next to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want the navigation menu to go on the right side; Just add the class `navbar-right` in your code as shown below.

```
   <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
    );
    ?>
```